# add inquiry in new tab

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, theme

I have a theme installed but i wanted the Send inquiry form in New tab.
I am unable to figure out how i can do it. Looked in all the layout and catlog files.

There is a inquiry.xml with code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <layout version="0.1.0">
    <!--
    Product view
    -->
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="inquiry/inquiry" name="product.inquiry" as="inquiry" template="inquiry/form/inquiry.phtml" after="reviews">
                <action method="addToParentGroup">
                    <group>detailed_info</group>
                </action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value">

                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view> </layout>
```

How should i create a new tab view page.
http://www.omegakart.com/security-solutions/cctv-camera/test-camera2.html#.VXRFAc-qqkr

Comment: Im having the same issue. I cant find an email inquiry extesion that removes the price and changes the button to inquiry for Magento 1. I see many for Magento 2 but none for Magento 1 Can anyone help me please?

Comment: this does not seem to be answer. If you have the same or similar problem, you can comment on the post or ask your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add something like this in your product view template

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('inquiry') ?>
```

Comment: I did try and add that under view.phtml but did not work.

Comment: I did some workaround with the guidance you gave and it worked.